# Vetor em C- Program received signal, Segementation fault

Tags: c, funções, array

Olá,
Elaborei uma função que verifica se um número está presente em um vetor. A
função recebe como parâmetros o vetor, o valor a ser verificado e o numero de
elementos existentes no mesmo. E retorna 1 (um) se o elemento existir no vetor ou zero caso não exista. Inicialize o vetor com os valores que você  desejar e permita que o usuário insira, através do teclado, a constante a ser procurada. Ao final do processamento o programa deve comunicar ao usuário se a constante foi encontrada ou não.

Mas, após o usuário inserir o numero a ser procurado o compilador trava. Usei o Debug da erro de Program received signal, Segementation fault.. Creio que o erro está na chamada da função mas tentei de outras formas e também não dá. Ajuda por favor!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
#define MAX 100

int verifica_vetor(int vet[MAX],int n, int tam){//funcao verifica se o vetor contem o numero
int i;
 for ( i=0;i<=tam;i++){//laco percorre o vetor
    if (n==vet[i]){//verifica se o num digitado esta em alguma das posicoes do vetor
      printf("O valor foi encontrado: %d",vet[i]);
      return 1;
    }else{
      printf("\nO valor não foi encontrado.");
      return 0;
    }
}

}
    main() {
    int k,i,num, vetor[MAX];
    srand(time(NULL));

    printf("\n Informe o tamanho do vetor: ");
    scanf("%d",&k);

    for ( i = 0; i < k; i++)    {//preenche o vetor com numero aleatorios de 0 ao numero digitado
        vetor[i] = rand() % k + 1;

        printf("Vetor[%d] : %d" , i+1,  vetor[i]);//vai mostrando o veto
        printf("\n");

    }

    printf("\n Informe o numero que deseja procurar no vetor: ");
    scanf("%d",num);

    verifica_vetor(vetor,num, k);//chama a funcao de verificar

    system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vamos la amigo, melhorei um pouco seu codigo e agora esta funcionando 100%

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
#define MAX 100

int verifica_vetor(int *num, int vetor[MAX], int k){
    int i, aux = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < k; i++){
        if (*num == vetor[i]){
            aux++;
        }
    }

    if (aux != 0){
        printf("O numero existe no vetor!\n");
        return 0;
        }else{
            printf("O numero nao existe no vetor\n.");
            return 1;
        }
}

void main() {
    int k,i,num, vetor[MAX];

    srand(time(NULL));

    printf("\n Informe o tamanho do vetor: ");
    scanf("%d",&k);

    for ( i = 0; i < k; i++)    {//preenche o vetor com numero aleatorios de 0 ao numero digitado
        vetor[i] = rand() % k + 1;

        printf("Vetor[%d] : %d" , i+1,  vetor[i]);//vai mostrando o veto
        printf("\n");

    }

    printf("\n Informe o numero que deseja procurar no vetor: ");
    scanf("%d",&num);

    verifica_vetor(&num, vetor, k);//chama a funcao de verificar

    system("pause");
}
```

Tudo que fiz foi adicionar uma nova logica para ele verificar todos os numeros dentro do vetor primeiro e fora da busca ai sim responder se o seu vetor tem aquele valor requisitado.
Passei alguns parametros por referencia para evitar algum tipo de erro (como numeros que nao foram inseridos).

Comment: Obrigado! me salvou

Comment: Deixa aquele up na resposta pra quem for vim ver esse problema ja veja a resposta que lhe ajudou. ;D

Answer (score 1):

Quando eu compilo o seu código, ele mostra o seguinte *warning*:

```
warning C4700: uninitialized local variable 'num' used
```

Quando você está lendo esse valor, você precisa passar o endereço dessa variável, e não o seu valor, para `scanf`:

```
scanf("%d", &num);
```

Note que a sua lógica da procura (`verifica_vetor`) também não funciona: ela só olha para o primeiro elemento do vetor.

Comment: nossa , não tinha percebido essa, que gafe : scanf("%d", &num); 
Quanto ao (verifica_vetor) , porque só olha o primeiro elemento se eu fiz esse for que percorre todo o vetor?
for ( i=0;i<=tam;i++)